# Limit the date to today and block the previous dates

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in JavaScript, I know the subject exists on StackOverFlow as here below but I don't understand.

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

I would like to handle the previous dates for example: We are on `28-05-2020`, if the user enters on `27-05-2020` an error message should appear.

For information, I am obliged to use JavaScript to handle the dates.

```js
function validation()
{
    const date_start = document.getElementById('date_start').value;
    const inputDate = new Date(date_start);
    
    const dayFromImputDate = inputDate.getFullYear(); // previous day
    
    const now = new Date();
    const dateNow = now.getFullYear();

    if(dayFromImputDatee < dateNow) {
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** Error date ! ";
        return false;
    }

    if(date_start == ""){
        document.getElementById('date_startError').innerHTML = " ** date empty ! ";
        return false;
    }



    console.log("Date is valid");
    return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
<br>
<label>Date start : </label>
<br>
<input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start">
<br>
<span id="date_startError"></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help and your time.

Comment: there is a typo : `dayFromImputDatee` must be `dayFromImputDate`

Comment: What is the problem here? The _"...but I don't understand"_ part or the error message from the typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if input date is less than today's date using `<` operator

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const error = document.getElementById('date_startError');

function validation(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const startDate = form.elements['date_start'].value;

  if (!startDate) {
    error.innerHTML = " ** date empty ! ";
    return;
  }

  const inputDate = new Date(startDate).getDate();
  const today = new Date().getDate();

  if (inputDate < today || !inputDate.valueOf()) {
    error.innerHTML = " ** Error date ! ";
    return;
  }

  error.innerHTML = "date is valid";
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="validation(event)">
  <br>
  <label>Date start : </label>
  <br>
  <input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start" placeholder="2020-05-28">
  <br>
  <span id="date_startError"></span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Yousaf, it's ok thank you a lot but it's possible to use my validation function ? Because, I yet am beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Because HTML5 already has `min` and `max` attributes for the `date` input type, you don't need to implement a separate validation function to accomplish this. Here is a simpler way:

```
var date = new Date();
var iso_date = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
document.getElementById("date_start").setAttribute('min', iso_date);
```

Basically, you just get a new `Date()` object, extract and format it into an ISO 8601 date format, and set it into the `min` attribute. This also limits the browser selection calendar to future dates only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you are trying to restrict a date form input to the current day or some future date.
To check whether a date is valid you could do this:

```
    let earliestPossibleDate = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()
    );
    let isValidDate = date_start >= earliestPossibleDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. You need to get your **Current Date** and set time to start of day.
2. You need to get your **Selected Date** and set time to start of day
3. Compare whether **Selected Date is Greater or Equal to the Current Date**.

Note that when you compare dates, you need to also consider the time.
Most calendar tools, include the time as a response to the selected date. You need to be aware of that.

This doesn't include other date validations. This will only solve the current problem at hand. Hope this helps! =)

```
const isValidDate = (selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = new Date();

    // reset to start of day
    currentDate.setHours(0);
    currentDate.setMinutes(0);
    currentDate.setSeconds(0);
    currentDate.setMilliseconds(0);

    const newDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    newDate.setHours(0);
    newDate.setMinutes(0);
    newDate.setSeconds(0);
    newDate.setMilliseconds(0);

    return newDate.getTime() >= currentDate.getTime();
}
```

To use, simply throw the selected date in the function. Should return true if the date is greater or equal to the date today.

```
isValidDate(selectedDateFromDatePicker);
```